# Firebase Jira Integration: Unable to verify credentials. Error Saving Settings

Tags: firebase, jira, integration, credentials

When i try to follow steps for Jira Server integration with Firebase, and enter Jira Project URL and Credentials (for valid credentials), i got following message:

`Error saving settings. Unable to verify credentials.`

For wrong credentials i get:
`Invalid login credentials.`

We're using Jira Data Centre and not Jira Cloud.

What could be the reason and is it even possible to integrate it with this solution?

I tried both wrong and valid credentials and get the different message. Our IT told me we don't use Jira Cloud but Jira Data Centre, which could be then the option Jira Server, and i followed these steps:
[Firebase Documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9118259#:%7E:text=Verify%20%26%20save.-,Jira%20Server,-In%20the%20Firebase)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase documentation you've provided a link to says, in a BIG RED WARNING box:

**"This Firebase integration supports Jira Software Cloud but not Jira on-premise implementations."**

Given that Jira Data Center is an on-premise product....well, I guess you might be able to work it out from here.

Comment: what is then difference between "Jira Server" and "Jira Data Center"?

Comment: @domorocki Have you ever heard of a thing called Google? You should try it!!